# Valgrind Memory Leak in a multi-class level constructor for a dungeoncrawler in c++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I ran into a small memory leak in my current project developing a small dungeoncrawler in c++.
Valgrind shows me that I am leaking `0 bytes in 1 blocks are definetly lost in loss record 1 of 38, Location level.cpp:6:0` the line is my constructor definition.
I just can't seem to find the problem, because after what I read about Valgrind the only possible explanation of this problem is if I created an Array of length 0 which would then be lost, but this is not the case in my Code.

Are there any other explanations for how that valgrind message could happen?

I'd rather not upload the code onto here because the project is rather large and I am not sure if the code would be helpful.

Edit 1:

```
Level::Level(const std::string& levelFileName)
{

    auto nodes = loadNodesFromLevelFile(levelFileName);
    std::vector<Node> switches;
    std::vector<Node> portals;

    for(const auto& node : nodes)
    {
        const auto nodeName = node.name;
        if(nodeName == "Map Information")
        {
            setHeight(node.get<int>("rows"));
            setWidth(node.get<int>("cols"));
            m_gameboard = new Tile**[m_height];

            for(auto row = 0; row < m_height; ++row)
            {
                m_gameboard[row] = new Tile*[m_width];
            }
        }
        if(nodeName == "Wall")
        {
            auto col = node.get<int>("col");
            auto row = node.get<int>("row");
            m_gameboard[row][col] = new Wall(row, col);
        }
        if(nodeName == "Floor")
        {
            auto col = node.get<int>("col");
            auto row = node.get<int>("row");
            m_gameboard[row][col] = new Floor(row, col);
        }
        if(nodeName == "Door")
        {
            auto col = node.get<int>("col");
            auto row = node.get<int>("row");
            m_gameboard[row][col] = new Door(row, col);
        }
        if(nodeName == "Portal")
        {
            auto col = node.get<int>("col");
            auto row = node.get<int>("row");
            m_gameboard[row][col] = new Portal(row, col, nullptr);
            portals.push_back(node);
        }
        if(nodeName == "Switch")
        {
            switches.push_back(node);
        }
        if(nodeName == "Character")
        {
            auto col = node.get<int>("col");
            auto row = node.get<int>("row");
            auto icon = node.get<char>("icon");
            placeCharacter(new Character(icon), row, col);
        }
    }
    for(const auto& portalNode : portals)
    {
        const auto row = portalNode.get<int>("row");
        const auto col = portalNode.get<int>("col");
        const auto destRow = portalNode.get<int>("destrow");
        const auto destCol = portalNode.get<int>("destcol");

        auto* portal = static_cast<Portal*>(m_gameboard[row][col]);
        auto* destination = static_cast<Portal*>(m_gameboard[destRow][destCol]);
        portal->setDestination(destination);
    }



    for(const auto& s : switches)
    {
        const auto row = s.get<int>("row");
        const auto col = s.get<int>("col");
        const auto destRows = s.get<std::vector<int>>("destrows");
        const auto destCols = s.get<std::vector<int>>("destcols");

        auto* sw = new Switch(row, col);
        m_gameboard[row][col] = sw;
        for(ulong i = 0; i < destRows.size(); ++i)
        {
            auto* target = m_gameboard[destRows[i]][destCols[i]];
            sw->attach(dynamic_cast<Door*>(target));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the constructor for my level  (which starts at line 6).

Comment: You could at least show the code at "Location level.cpp:6:0" or do you want us to completely guess?

Comment: Please see [mre]. The entire code base would be too much to post, but it would be helpful if you could reduce the amount of code needed to reproduce the problem. If you're lucky, try a `main` function that constructs your object then exits. If Valgrind reports the error for this, reduce the class definition to the bare minimum needed to keep the leak. (You might also look for 0-length arrays of your class. Not sure if that would trigger this message, but worth looking into.)

Comment: Use container classes/smart pointers, they are there for a reason. Never use naked `new`/`delete` unless you are making a container class or smart pointers. But even then, you may build upon existing containers.

Comment: How do you initialize `m_width` and `m_height`?

Comment: simple setter functions

```
void Level::setHeight(int height)
{
    m_height = height;
}



void Level::setWidth(int width)
{
    m_width = width;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okey, by now I figured out why my programm was loosing bytes.

In my level.h I initialized the tile*** m_gameboard with the uninitialized value of m_height.

`Tile*** m_gameboard = new Tile**[m_height];`

which was overriden in my constructor. Therefor the 0 bytes were lost.

Thanks for every suggestion.